# Updating a single field in mongoldb collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to update the field `editing`:

```
{
    "_id" : "C7PgEtzToNwHgJb6e",
    "metadata" : {
        "type" : "anything",
        "editing" : false
    }
}
```

If I do...

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: { metadata: { editing: true } } }
);
```

... the field `type` will be removed:

```
{
    "_id" : "C7PgEtzToNwHgJb6e",
    "metadata" : {
        "editing" : true
    }
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sym3tri/858142

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I partially update an object in MongoDB so the new object will overlay / merge with the existing one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290621/how-do-i-partially-update-an-object-in-mongodb-so-the-new-object-will-overlay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dot` notation you can ensure only the field value is updated instead of the entire field:

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: id },
   { $set: { "metadata.editing": true } } }
);
```