# Partially updating nested objects with multiple values Express.js MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

First of all, I have read [this stack overflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290621/how-do-i-partially-update-an-object-in-mongodb-so-the-new-object-will-overlay) which addresses this problem partially but I need to dynamically add multiple entries and cannot apply the answers there to this problem.

I have a website with polls (using express and the mongodb driver) and I want users to be able to add additional options to the polls after they have submitted it (they can only add additional items, they cannot edit preexisting items).

All options (the possible answers) are labelled as `answer` followed by a number (maximum of 5).

So in the database we have:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58cdf0023cefa56136afb50f"
    },
    "question": "Who is the best Bob?",
    "options": {
        "answer1": {
            "option": "Bob Dylan",
            "votes": 2
        },
        "answer2": {
            "option": "Bob Geldof",
            "votes": 0
        }
    }
}
```

So with this entry, the user can add up to three additional answer options.

When I hard-code the additional answer name (e.g. `answer3` in this db example) I can update the nested `options` property.

```
var toInsert = { options: 
   { answer3: { option: 'Bob Saget', votes: 0 },
     answer4: { option: 'Bob Marley', votes: 0 } } }

  db.collection('questions')
  .findOneAndUpdate({"_id": questionId}, {$set : {'options.answer3': [toInsert.answer3]}}, {upsert: true}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.send(err)
    res.send("worked");
  })
```

EDIT: I have just realized his has a bug in it also, so I can't even hard-code the answer properly. However, I will leave this here for clarity.

But what I need to do is dynamically update that nested `options` object with 1-3 possible new options (depending on what the user wants) and leave the pre-existing data alone in the `options` object. In the example code above, I would want to insert both `answer3` and `answer4` from `toInsert`.

I'm very new to Node and MongoDB and my idea of "Hey, I can put it through a `for loop`" seems like a bad idea even if I could get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you are after by replacing the answer documents with options embedded array documents.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58cdf0023cefa56136afb50f"
    },
    "question": "Who is the best Bob?",
    "options": [
        {
            "answer" : "answer1",
            "option": "Bob Dylan",
            "votes": 2
        },
        {
            "answer" : "answer2",
            "option": "Bob Geldof",
            "votes": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Now you can easily add embedded documents to the options by using `$each` with `$push` operator.

```
db.collection('questions')
  .findOneAndUpdate({"_id": questionId}, {$push: { options: { $each: [ { answer: "answer3", option: 'Bob Saget', votes: 0 },{ answer: "answer4", option: 'Bob Marley', votes: 0 } ] } } } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is best way to do this but what you could do is first run `findOne` query to find document you want to modify and then use `Object.assign()` on returned document to add options from other object and then replace that document with updated one using `replaceOne`.

```js
col.findOne(
  {_id: mongodb.ObjectId('IdOfObject')},
  function(err, doc) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    Object.assign(doc.options, toInsert.options)

    col.replaceOne(
      {_id: mongodb.ObjectId('IdOfObject')},
      doc,
      function(e, d) {
        if (e) console.log(e)
        else console.log('Object Updated.')
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Updated object will look like this

```
{ _id: 58ce98cbd85b01133c4c3615,
  question: 'Who is the best Bob?',
  options:
   { answer1: { option: 'Bob Dylan', votes: 2 },
     answer2: { option: 'Bob Geldof', votes: 0 },
     answer3: { option: 'Bob Saget', votes: 0 },
     answer4: { option: 'Bob Marley', votes: 0 } } }
```