# Golang MGO - Insert or update not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, go, upsert

I'm running a website in Go and I'm using the [MGO](https://labix.org/mgo) package to connect with my MongoDB database.

I am handling a user's sign in, and I am trying to use the func [`Upsert()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Upsert) to update a user if they exist in the database, otherwise insert them.

The issue is, when I run [`Upsert()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Upsert) (the code below), it replaces all fields rather than updating only the present fields in the second argument's `bson.M{}`.

```
db.C("users").Upsert(
    bson.M{"email": "someone@gmail.com"}, // Which doucment to upsert
    bson.M{"displayName": "Johhny"}, // What to replace
)
```

---

**A visual example of what I'm trying to explain.**

An existing database document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e7589bab64da55ebcf5d25"),
    "email" : "someone@gmail.com",
    "password" : "",
    "age": 69,
    "displayName" : "Someone!"
}
```

After running:

```
db.C("users").Upsert(
    bson.M{"email": "someone@gmail.com"},
    bson.M{"displayName": "My name was updated"},
)
```

The document becomes:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e789feab64da55ebcf691c"),
    "displayName" : "My name was updated"
}
```

When I expected the document to become:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e7589bab64da55ebcf5d25"),
    "email" : "someone@gmail.com",
    "password" : "",
    "age": 69,
    "displayName" : "My name was updated" // This should be updated, all others should be left untouched
}
```

---

**Finally my question.**

How can I update a document if it already exists in a MongoDB collection, otherwise insert it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to update a document with fields that you provide and ignore all other fields then I think it's not possible without a select first.

[See this question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290621/how-do-i-partially-update-an-object-in-mongodb-so-the-new-object-will-overlay)

*EDIT:*
Try:

```
db.C("users").Upsert(
    bson.M{"email": "someone@gmail.com"},
    bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"displayName": "My name was updated"}},
)
```

Comment: Are you saying I need to make two queries to the MongoDB? Select, check for error then (update if it doesn't exist/insert if it exists) sort of thing?

Comment: Sorry I miss understood, you need to use the `$set` operator
Something like:
`bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"displayName": "My name was updated"}}`

Comment: One more quick question... When using `Update()`, do I need to use "$set" as a bson key?

Comment: `$set` replaces the value of the field with the value given, it lets you update just that field. If you want to update a part of a doc, and not the whole thing, try using `$set`, if you want to update the whole doc, try leaving it off.