# How to insert a document if a filter returns nothing, otherwise replace the document found in mongodb with go?

Tags: database, mongodb, go, insert

I am not using the MGO package like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278696/golang-mgo-insert-or-update-not-working-as-expected) example, just the active repo from [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver).

I am having a hard time reading the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/go). Basically, I have a bson.M object that I want to replace the current one, and if that one doesn't exist, insert it.

Currently my code looks like:

```golang
updateFilter := bson.D{{"from_symbol", fromSymbol}, {"to_symbol", strings.ToUpper(currency["to_symbol"].(string))}}
// The above seems to be correctly finding the documents I want
// currency is my bson.M object

_, err := collection.ReplaceOne(ctx, updateFilter, currency)
// However this line will not additionally insert if the object is not found, it is replacing fine
```

I'm sure I could manually run *another* query looking to see if the document exists, but that seems unnecessary. 
Thank you!

---

EDIT:

It looks like there should be a way to do something with `replaceOptions`, [see the documentation](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.ReplaceOne).

```golang
upsert := options.ReplaceOptions{Upsert: true}
_, err := collection.ReplaceOne(ctx, updateFilter, currency, upset)
```

However this gives me the error:

```
cannot use true (type bool) as type *bool in field value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SetUpsert` function:

```
collection.ReplaceOne(ctx,filter,newDoc,options.Replace().SetUpsert(true))
```