# How to update the value of a particular array element in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to update the value of shopping and food for particular array element in mongo db ?

**MongoDB Document :**

```
   {
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5e131eb4ea0c191cdc06f96b",
            "firstName": "Anirudh",
            "lastName": "Singla",
            "gender": "Male",
            "username": "anirudhsingla8",
            "email": "anirudhsingla8@gmail.com",
            "password": "rj13sl1608",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "card_number": "1014220122322233",
                    "shopping": 0,
                    "food": 0
                },
                {
                    "card_number": "1014220122322234",
                    "shopping": 0,
                    "food": 0
                }
           }
         ]
}
```

I was trying to update the value in subelement of array like the current value of shopping for `"card_number"="1014220122322234"` is `0`. but I want to update it according to user need.like if user enter `10` then it should be updated to `0+10=10`, if it is `10`  and user enter `16` then it should be updated to `10+16=26` like this. But I am not able to figure out query for this type of update on mongodb docs.

Comment: Since `cards` are nested documents, you need to read the document from the db first, make the necessary changes in memory and save it back. Another option is using [partial update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16119136/210085).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - Update objects in a document's array (nested updating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-objects-in-a-documents-array-nested-updating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [positional($) operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

```
User.update(
  {
    _id: userId,
    'cards.card_number': '1014220122322233'
  },
  {
    $inc: { 'cards.$.shopping': 1, 'cards.$.food': 1 }
  }
);
```

This would increment both shopping, food by 1.

Comment: Thanks 
is it possible to decrement the value also.

Comment: yeap just use negative numbers `$inc: { 'cards.$.shopping': -1, 'cards.$.food': -1 }`