# looking for a way to update mongoDB data(array, which has 21 fields in it) with overwriting using REST API Patch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js, rest

As the title above, I am looking for a way to
update mongoDB data(array, which has 21 fields in it) with overwriting using REST API Patch

below is my MongoDB Collection schema
('-' mark means a lower level of the top-level component)

| Key | Type |
| --- | --- |
| _id | ObjectId |
| ... | ... |
| transactionLogs_docs | Array |
| - [0] | Object |
| - transactionID | String |
| - transactionType | String |
| - userId | String |
| - firstName | String |
| - lastName | String |
| - ... | ... |

currently with my code(coded with nodejs, express, vuejs, vuetify)
when I update some data in the collection using REST API Patch,
the data keys are gone except the one that I listed in the code.

What I wanna do is, partially update and replace values in the collection's transactionLogs_docs[0].fields and other fields out of transactionLogs_docs.
(what I didn't mention in code, just maintain the original data)

below is my server-side patch function code.

```
// Modify Post
router.patch('/:id', async(req, res) => {
    const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
    await posts.updateOne(
        { "_id" : new mongodb.ObjectID(req.params.id) },
        {$set: {
            "transactionLogs_docs": {
                "0": {
                    "transactionId": req.body.transactionId, 
                    "transactionType": req.body.transactionType,
                    "userId": req.body.userId,
                    "firstName": req.body.firstName, 
                    "lastName": req.body.lastName              
                }
            },        
            "createdAt": req.body.createdAt, 
            "deviceName": req.body.deviceName, 
            "passCheck": req.body.passCheck,
            "max_temp": req.body.max_temp
        }},     
        { upsert: true }
    );
    res.status(201).send();
});
```

Comment: set value like this `transactionLogs_docs.0.transactionId: req.body.transactionId` change do same for every fields in `transactionLogs_docs`,

Comment: This is happening because you are using `$set` and the field values you are receiving in `req.body` is `undefined`. MongoDB will explicitly change those values to `null`

Comment: @turivishal you definitely saved my day. I appreciate your advice thanks :)

Comment: you can see also the article below. [mongodb-partially-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290621/how-do-i-partially-update-an-object-in-mongodb-so-the-new-object-will-overlay)